# What is thin as night and soft as sand, will break the teeth but not the hand?

Tags: riddle

This is a riddle posed by a dragon in the short story [Maybe Just Go Up There and Talk to It](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2740766) by Scott Lynch. The dragon does not give the answer to the riddle and it is entirely possible that it has no answer and the author is just toying with the reader.

Since the story does not give the solution I cannot confirm any answer as correct, but I'm hoping there will be an answer sufficiently plausible that I'll find myself thinking *Oh, of course!*.

Comment: @Randal'Thor SFF and Puzzling in one! :-)

Comment: I am confused by the expression "thin as night". Is it a common phrase?

Comment: @drd sounds like the night air is thin and cold?

Comment: Maybe ask the author?  scott[a t]scottlynch[d o t].us

Comment: I have no problem imagining thin night. Night is a thin black blanket with stars, covering the Earth's sphere. Like a wrapping.

Comment: googling for "thin as night" became NSFW surprisingly quickly. I'm out =P

Comment: @StianYttervik the problems aren't in the words, but in the search engine that goes by popularity nowadays. And as that puppet monster sang, "The Internet is for ..."

Comment: I don't see why this question has been marked as off-topic. It contains both a riddle and an invitation to a discussion of the role of a riddle in a story.

Answer (score 21):

First thought is

> Hair

Because

> It's thin.  It's soft.  It will break the teeth of a comb eventually, but hopefully your Welsh comb will make it through undamaged.

Caveat: I have no idea what "thin as night" means.  "Soft as sand" isn't going to work if I go by the Mohs scale either.

Comment: I think this makes more sense than the other answer, in view of the specific word choice "*break* the teeth".

Comment: Yes, and *hair black as night* is a common cliché in fantasy books.

Comment: This is my answer too!

Answer (score 21):

Given the context of the story (available [here](https://www.grimdarkmagazine.com/review-the-book-of-dragons-ed-jonathan-strahan/)), maybe:

> an empty promise.

Because it

> has no substance

> offers no support

> stops speech

> doesn't stop action

Answer (score 14):

> Sugar

Maybe my reasoning is a bit too grounded in our world, but here goes:

> "Thin as night": Grains of sugar can be small... yeah, this is a bit of a stretch
>
>  "soft as sand": Sugar is quite similar to sand if you hold it in your hand and it's all dry
>
>  "will break the teeth": Cavities
>
>  "but not the hand": Sugar on skin won't do much, especially on non-sensitive areas like the hand. There are even "sugar scrubs" that some people use to make their skin *better*, although after a few Google searches, I'm not sure how to find reliable information on whether they actually work or are beneficial...

Comment: My thought on the first part is that spread thinly, it looks like stars in the night sky.

Comment: If you want evidence that sugar helps clean the skin, try it.  Get your hands covered in something difficult to remove, such as sump oil.  Clean it off with washing up liquid and sugar (or salt, you just need "bits").  Nothing else short of [specalised products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarfega) will work as well.

Answer (score 10):

It seems like the answer could be:

> Time

Because:

"thin as night"

> seems to mean something **intangible**.

"soft as sand"

> is reminiscent of an **hourglass**. And, one doesn't necessarily notice the passage of time as it softly and quietly slides past.

"will break the teeth"

> Time will **break the teeth of a clock's gears**, as they wear down through the ages. Also, the riddle specifies "the teeth", not "your teeth" or "one's teeth", so it seems to imply that an object or concept is being affected, not a creature that has teeth. And lastly, the riddle says the answer "will" break the teeth, implying that this won't happen until the future.

"but not the hand"

> but **the clock's hands are likely to survive** even after the clock has stopped. And again, the riddle seems to imply an object or concept is being affected, instead of a creature that has a hand.

Answer (score 7):

A somewhat different take, but perhaps it's

> a smile

because

> Smiles can be thin, though means the are insincere.
>  Smiles can also be seen as soft (though if it does mean rough like sand can be, a harder, rougher smile may be menacing)
>  Break the teeth may mean to show them, break into view. A smile would not show or cause a hand to break into view
>
>  Coming from a Dragon could be a warning that what starts as a light, disarming smile could lead to danger you don't want from a dragon...it bearing its teeth to you

Answer (score 5):

Can it be

> A piece of string

Because

> It is very thin.
>
>  It is soft if the fabric is right (silk or cotton)
>
>  Can be used to pluck out baby teeth (The string and doorknob method).
>
>  Can't break your hand (but can be broken by it).

Comment: This is probably too literal. The solution, if there is one, is likely to be metaphorical or otherwise figurative.

Comment: Yeah, agree with Daniel, also I don't think the method you describe breaks the tooth (just removes it).

Comment: @hexomino You mean figuratively breaks it not literally ;-)

Comment: Neither, I would say.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go.for

> **Rain**

as a first try. Because:

> **thin as night and soft as sand** Rain can be thin and soft indeed. **will break the teeth** there are many monolithic rock formations known as "teeth". They can be caused - and also eroded/destroyed - by water erosion, and therefore at times by rain. **but not the hand** It might erode rock, but your hand won't be hurt by a rain shower.

Answer (score 4):

What about

> Candy floss/cotton candy

It mostly fits, especially if we think of "break the teeth" as

> rotting them away if you eat too much.

Comment: +1 for a reasonable guess in our world, but the riddle was posed by a dragon in a fantasy-fiction world where this might not exist.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, the answer is

> sand

thin as night

> rather metaphorically, but fine sand is thin and of course, there is [black sand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_sand)

and soft as sand

> duh

will break the teeth

> sand, if it gets mixed into your food can wear down your teeth pretty thoroughly - [this plagued ancient Egyptians](https://www.nature.com/articles/sj.bdj.2009.309) with excessive dental damage, with the sand either blown from the desert or introduced by grinding the grain with sandstone hand mills

but not the hand?

> handling sand is, of course, perfectly safe (unless in very unusual situations)

Comment: poor egyptians...

Answer (score 3):

And another:

> Logic.
> (It should appeal to a riddling dragon!)

Because:

> Logic is really **thin**, in fact razor-like in its approach. Whole arguments can turn on the meaning of one word, or one line of reasoning. It's **soft, like sand**, that piles up and only then becomes formidable. You can **cut (break) your teeth** on it (as the saying goes) in childhood and throughout life, as you learn, and it'll never relent from giving you new lessons to cut your teeth on in vain, if you become arrogant about your abilities, but you'll **never physically cut your hand** (or any other body part) on it.

It's just too dragon-y an answer not to give!

Answer (score 1):

There are similar answers already but I would like to be more precise:

> Cocoa powder

Explanation:

> Thin as night -it means dark colour and maybe also the size of its soft grains. 
>  Soft as sand -in its powder form. 
>  Will break the teeth -if you make chocolate or other sweets. 
>  But not the hand -because it is not very strong material itself at all.

Additionally:

> One could say that such a thing may not exist in a fantasy world. If so, why there is usually wheat and rye but cocoa tree not? As I can see, heroes and adventurers eat bread and drink beer very often. Fantasy worlds may have similar flora to ours or may not.

Answer (score -2):

There can be only one answer, the best answer, the answer to defeat all other answers:

> A silent fart

Because

> Thin and invisible like night air

> Soft, even fluffy

> Will make you gnash your teeth from the smell

> Won't escape if you stick your finger in your butthole